# How do remove the need to define a title in a Flutter widget?

Tags: flutter

I have the following Widget for my home view:

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {

  HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
}
```

That won't compile because `The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'HomeView'.`

I would like to not need to define this getter. What is the point of defining the title for a Widget anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your `home: HomeView(),` doesn't take any parameters

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomeView(),
    );
  }
}
```